# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver Error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

before marking this post as closed or duplicate i want to say that i have done all the things that are mentioned on similar posts but none of them worked.

I have 2 receivers which i get data from. So i want to register the receivers when the activity starts and unregister them when the activity is not visible.

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CheckNetworkStatusReceiver checkNetworkStatusReceiver;
    private CheckBatteryStatusReceiver checkBatteryStatusReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkConnection();
    }
    public void checkConnection() {
        if(!ConnectionManager.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
           ConnectionManager.wifiSettingsDialog(MainActivity.this).show();
        }else{
            registerReceivers();
        }
    }

    public void registerReceivers() {
        checkNetworkStatusReceiver = new CheckNetworkStatusReceiver();
        checkBatteryStatusReceiver = new CheckBatteryStatusReceiver();
        registerReceiver(checkNetworkStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.INTENT_FILTER_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE));
        registerReceiver(checkBatteryStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(checkNetworkStatusReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(checkBatteryStatusReceiver);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceivers();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        registerReceivers();
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        try{
            unregisterReceiver(checkNetworkStatusReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(checkBatteryStatusReceiver);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The receiver code:

```
public class CheckNetworkStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null){
            Log.e("Action ",intent.getAction());
            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.INTENT_FILTER_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE)) {
                if (!ConnectionManager.isNetworkAvailable(context)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (MobileDataManager.slowInternetConnection(context)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.slow_internet_delay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the battery receiver:

```
public class CheckBatteryStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null){
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            if (level <= 15){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Batter level " + level + "% is very low. Please connect to a charger.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i get the error on the `registerReceivers()` method. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is within your CheckNetworkStatusReceiver and CheckBatteryStatusReceiver class. Can you provide the code of the classeS?

Comment: check the updated question

Comment: registerReceiver in onResume and unregisterReceiver in onPasue()  remove from other places

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You register the receivers in `onCreate()` and then again in `onResume()`. This will leak the receivers that you registered in `onCreate()`, because you overwrite the variables you are using to hold references to them every time `registerReceivers()` is called.

This is not very robust code. You don't need to create new instances of the `BroadcastReceiver` every time. What you should do is to create one instance of each `BroadcastReceiver` in `onCreate()`. Then declare a boolean member variable in your class called `receiversRegistered`. In `registerReceivers()` you should check this boolean. If it is `true`, the receivers are already registered and you should do nothing. If not, register the receivers and then set the boolean to `true`. When you unregister the receivers, set the boolean to `false`.

---

**EDIT: Here it is all done for you:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CheckNetworkStatusReceiver checkNetworkStatusReceiver;
    private CheckBatteryStatusReceiver checkBatteryStatusReceiver;
    private boolean receiversRegistered;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkNetworkStatusReceiver = new CheckNetworkStatusReceiver();
        checkBatteryStatusReceiver = new CheckBatteryStatusReceiver();
        checkConnection();
    }
    public void checkConnection() {
        if(!ConnectionManager.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
           ConnectionManager.wifiSettingsDialog(MainActivity.this).show();
        }else{
            registerReceivers();
        }
    }

    public void registerReceivers() {
        // Only register if not already registered
        if (!receiversRegistered) {
            registerReceiver(checkNetworkStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.INTENT_FILTER_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE));
            registerReceiver(checkBatteryStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            receiversRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (receiversRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(checkNetworkStatusReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(checkBatteryStatusReceiver);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceivers();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        registerReceivers();
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (receiversRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(checkNetworkStatusReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(checkBatteryStatusReceiver);
            receiversRegistered = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well the only reason i am doing this is because there is no actual way to check if the receivers are already registered unless you make a custom handler to save the registered receivers in the loop and then loop through them to check if they are registered. But this takes time and slows performance i believe

Comment: The code I just explained to you ensures that you only have one instance and you only register them if they aren't registered. What's the problem now?

Comment: you say that " If it is true, the receivers are already registered and you should do nothing. If not, register the receivers and then set the boolean to true. When you unregister the receivers, set the boolean to false" well the problem is that you cannot just set a boolean and check if they are registered but only if they have instance. If they have instance it does not mean that they are also registered.

Comment: You set the flag when you register the receivers. Then you know if the flag is `true`, the receivers are registered.

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem due to multiple instances of receiver, and that fixed my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `unregisterReceiver` inside `onPause` not in `onDestroy`.

When your activity is moved in background `onDestroy` is not called. The activity is only paused. `onDestroy` is called when the app is closed manually or by the system.

(`onPause` is called before `onDestroy` in above situation)

Comment: @patriarch Where do you get the leak? When are you registering the receivers?

Comment: i register the receivers only when it is not connected to the internet

Comment: @patriarch I understand. Do you get a sracktrace of the leak? Can you update the question with it?